# Как нажать комбинацию клавиш с помощью Pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, pyautogui

Как можно нажать комбинацию клавиш например win + r с помощью библиотеки Pyautogui
пробовал сделать вот так `pg.typewrite("win + r")` но в таком случае просто выводилось win + r, win нажималась не как клавиша а как буквы w + i + n
так же пробовал `pg.typewrite(["win"] + ["r"])` и пробовал

```
pg.typewrite(["win"])
pg.typewrite(["r"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во так:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так:

```
Pyautogui.press('win','r')
```